# App crashes when going back from view controller with tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview, afnetworking

I have a view controller with a table view with images init.
I'm loading the images with AFNetworking, and sometimes (mostly when my internet connection is slow) when I click on the backbuttonitem in the view controller and entering the rootviewcontroller the app crashes and I get the following message:

```
-[__NSCFDictionary numberOfSectionsInTableView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1f567e30
```

Why? 
Im using ARC.
Here's my code for loading images

```
if(item.thumb)
    {
        [cell.listItemImage setImage: item.thumb];

    }
    else
    {

        UIActivityIndicatorView *loadingSymbol = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
        loadingSymbol.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.listItemImage.frame.size.width, cell.listItemImage.frame.size.height);
        [cell.listItemImage addSubview: loadingSymbol];
        [loadingSymbol startAnimating];


        [cell.listItemImage setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: item.thumbUrl]]
                                  placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"transparent.png"]
                                           success:^(NSURLRequest *request , NSHTTPURLResponse *response , UIImage *image )
        {

                item.thumb = image;
            [cell setNeedsLayout];
                [loadingSymbol removeFromSuperview];
               [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

        }
        failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
        {
             NSLog(@"something went wrong wiv the images");
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
             //[loadingSymbol removeFromSuperview];

        }
         ];
    }
}
```

Would be really happy if someone could help me out here!

**EDIT:**

Solved my first problem. But now the app crashes when I'm scrolling in my table view. I think it has something to do with this following line:

```
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: According to the error message you managed to assign an NSDictionaryObject to some property where the framework expects a table delegate.

Comment: So this happens when the table view controller was released already but there is still data loaded in the background. Aparently you kept a reference to cell objects that should not exist any more. The cells itelf may still exists because of ARC depening whether this are strong or weak references.

Comment: I am not sure. Could that `[cell setNeedsLayout]' cause the cell and the table to be redrawn while the table or its controller don't exist any more? However, you should find some smarter solution. Either cancel all open requests when going back or don't process the data when the related view is not visible/existing any more.

Comment: Hm, how can i cancel the open requests when im going back?

Comment: Are you not using `UIImageView+AFNetworking`?

Comment: Yes I am? Code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following line in the `dealloc` method of the view controller. This worked for me in a project.

```
[[UIImageView af_sharedImageRequestOperationQueue] cancelAllOperations];
```

Your dealloc will look like this

```
-(void)dealloc
{
  [[UIImageView af_sharedImageRequestOperationQueue] cancelAllOperations];  

  //your other clean ups

  [super dealloc];
}
```

## Edit

In the header file of the ViewController, add an IBOutlet for the UITableView

`IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;`

Connect your `UITableView` to that outlet (`myTableView`) from Interface Builder.

Set the IBOutlet to nil in your dealloc

```
-(void)dealloc
{
   myTableView = nil;
   //your other clean ups
   [super dealloc];
}
```

Your success block should look like this

```
success:^(NSURLRequest *request , NSHTTPURLResponse *response , UIImage *image )
        {
           if(myTableView)
           {
              item.thumb = image;
              [cell setNeedsLayout];
              [loadingSymbol removeFromSuperview];
             [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
           }

        }
```

## Edit 2 (Scroll)

In your success block, instead of:

```
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Use:

```
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get the following error when i did what you said: no known class method for selector af_sharedImageRequestOperationQueue ?

Comment: did you put `#import "UIImageView+AFNetworking.h"` in your view controller file?  (include the **.h** file)

Comment: That is strange, because the latest version of the library has that method.. .(reference source code...)

I am going to edit the answer and add another workaround

Comment: (Don't mix list format with source format. SO will screw it up.)

Comment: Hm wait, now it's crashing when scrolling the tableview??

Comment: Get a new error now: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 5 beyond bounds [0 .. 4]' Hm?

Comment: And sometimes when im scrolling up and down in my tableview i get another error: EXC_BAD ACCESS code=1.. This is only when the internet connection is slow.

Comment: And now with this message: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 5 beyond bounds [0 .. 4]'

Comment: If this is a real life project (I mean, not a learning practice project), then I'd suggest you to use SDWebImage. Or, post your complete view controller code (both .h and .m) to find out the programming issues in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Problem: The network I/O finishes some time after your view controller has deallocated. As a result of the network I/O you reload some cells. Reloading the cells call the view controller (deallocated) for dataSource information and crashes.

Solution: You must nil out the table view delegate and dataSource in dealloc.

```
- (void)dealloc {
    // Cleanup table view 
    self.tableView.delegate = nil;
    self.tableView.dataSource = nil;

    // Stop network operations since their are not needed anymore.
    for (UITableViewCell *cell in [self.tableView visibleCells]) {
        [cell. listItemImage cancelImageRequestOperation];
    }
 }
```

In your cellForRowAtIndexPath cancel image download before reuse:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCellId";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    // Cancel network request
    [cell. listItemImage cancelImageRequestOperation];
    ...
}
```

Comment: I did that too, but my app is crashing when I'm scrolling up and down now. Happens when the internet connection is slow. Any ideas why?

Comment: I'm using UIImageView+AFNetworking and I think I'm using it the right way.. I also get this message, don't know what it means: purgeIdleCellConnections: found one to purge conn = 0x1d5bb9a0

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1774/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012992

Comment: Can you post your scrolling crash? The crash you mention in the post is related to dealloc not scrolling.

Comment: Edited my question, i don't know which code you want me to post? The app crashes when i'm scrolling yes, but i think it has something to do with the AFNetworking because i have a tableview without images which works fine.

Comment: I get an error if im using your af_sharedImageRequestOperationQueue saying "no know class method for selector"

Comment: I think the crashing has something to do with following code:  [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];